# Can't connect to any access point anymore after using wired conncetion

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, wireless-router

My Windows XP wireless stops working after using a wired connection. I can't see  the wireless network in the list of available wireless networks.

In wireless network connection properties, the *Use Windows to configure my network setting* box is checked. Wireless Zero Configuration is set to *started* and *automatic*.

I tried adding the network in *Wireless Network Connection Properties* / *Wireless Networks* tab, but that didn't work.

I am able to connect to the wireless network on another machine  I can still connect with Ethernet cable. I've made sure that the wireless network connection is enabled.

I use Norton antivirus.

Comment: You can't connect to THE SAME network with two different adapters, one of them needs to shutdown. Is this what you are trying to do? By the same network I meant network subnet, e.g. wired IP would be 192.168.0.5 and wifi would be 192.168.0.6

Comment: Im not trying to connect with wire and wireless at the same time at leas I don't think I am. Should local Area connection be disabled or am I not getting what you said?

Comment: Let's set things straight, maybe I didn't get you :-) So you have your cable **disconnected** and can't connect to Wifi, or you have a cable **connected** and wondering why WiFi disconnects? Or maybe something else?

Comment: right now Im on another pc, I have a Toshiba labtop that use to be connect witlessly to the internet one day I used a cable to connect and now I cant get it to connect with out a cable my ps3 is able to connect just fine witlessly. I have my cable disconnected and can't connect to Wifi. I cant see the network in the list of available wireless networks.

Comment: So the question should actually be `WHY can't I connect to my AP anymore`.

Comment: There you happy I change it but I stile have the same problem :P any farther advise I been work on this for like 3H now and I stile don't have fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WHY can't I connect to my WiFi network with my (insert device name here) anymore**

(this has nothing to do with whether or not were you using cable connection in the past).
In the meantime, you may have done one of the following, using AP's / router's interface:

- Most probable in your situation - you changed network TYPE on your AP from e.g. B to N, or 2.4GHz to 5Ghz or from 20 to 40Hz wide AND your device doesn't support that change.
- You made your network NOT broadcast SSID and you need to go to the (in this case Windows XP) network settings, find the "invisible" network in your saved WiFi network list and tick a box, that says "connect even if network doesn't broadcast SSID".
- Network was invisible anyway and you just changed password. With windows XP this case is resolvable in the same place as the previous one.
- Laptops have the ability to turn off the radio, look for the switch and flip it back, or look for keyboard shortcut / key and toggle it. This is even if the WiFi connection in Windows is turned on.
- your radio might have died on this computer

Can't think of anything else. Will update if anything comes to mind.

Comment: SSID is set up so it is broadcast because I was able to see it on my ps3 and I just checked. more news I just tuck it to a friends house to see if i could connect there of course I could not plus connect even if network doesn't broadcast SSID box is checked.

Comment: not shur about the other things